# Need to count german char in a string php

Tags: php

I need to count all german's char in a string with php.

I tryed like this:

```
$pattern = '/[äüöÄÜÖß]/';

$address = "Knnöstraße";

$counting = 0;

if(preg_match($pattern, $address )) {
    $counting ++;
}

echo $counting;
```

But it return me only 1. What s the best way to count special char?

With preg_all_match function it return me 4, but it must be 2:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $address, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

echo count($matches);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: it return me 4, but it must be 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the /u modifier, this way the pattern and the subject will be treated as UTF-8. This gives the correct result:

```
$pattern = '/[äüöÄÜÖß]/u';
$address = "Knnöstraße"; 
preg_match_all($pattern, $address, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
echo sizeof($matches);
```

which outputs 2, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could count a difference between original string and string without special german characters, like the following:

```
echo (mb_strlen($address, 'UTF-8') - strlen(str_replace(['ä', 'ü', 'ö', 'Ä', 'Ü', 'Ö', 'ß'], '', $address))); //2
```

Comment: `mb_strlen(str_replace(` ! What if other UTF8 stuff is in the string?

Comment: If you would have strings with unicode characters from different "alphabets" then you would need use mb_strlen() on both. Otherwise no need, and the speed difference is huge.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

In your example you just check if we have at least on character or not.

I suggest to use following code to solve your problem:

```
    $pattern = '/[äüöÄÜÖß]/u';
    $address = "Knnöstraße";
    $counting = preg_match($pattern, $address );
    if($counting === false) {
       throw new \Exception('Regexp error');
    }

    echo $counting;
```

BTW You should use "u" modifier to switch preg match to Unicode mode. You miss this flag that's why you get 4 instead of 2